# how to use text editors in Eclipse Mars programmatically, using the compatiblity layer?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am using the 3.x-4.x compatibility layer and I'm attempting to open and use editors. Our existing code looks like this in the class that implements `IPartListener2`:

```java
public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
        if (partRef instanceof IEditorReference) {
            //force editor area visible
            partRef.getPage().setEditorAreaVisible(true);
            // if the editors are currently minimimized and we try to maximize them, then we'll cause a bug.
            if (partRef.getPage().getPartState(partRef) == IWorkbenchPage.STATE_MINIMIZED) {
                return; // so exit here
            }
            //check preferences
            final boolean maximized = EnterpriseManager.isMaximized();
            if (maximized) {
                partRef.getPage().setPartState(partRef, 1);
            }
        } 
    }
```

The problem is now whenever an editor is opened in Mars, it doesn't open maximized as a tab on the page layout as before, but in a much smaller window size.

Also, selecting the Restore Icon on an open editor's rule bar causes erratic positioning of the editor with one section of the editor in one part of the layout and other sections displaying in other areas of the page layout.

How am I to implement correct, predictable usage of editors with the compatibility layer?

Comment: As a guess you could try using `Display.asyncExec` to run the code after the `partOpened` has finished. It may be that the Eclipse 4 does not like the state changes being done during the `partOpened` method itself.

Comment: Do you mean run `Display.asyncExec` in the calling method? We add our GlobalPartListener to the service in `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.preWindowOpen()`. So I'm just trying to understand where you are suggesting that call is made

Comment: Added an answer with what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing but it may be that Eclipse 4 does not like the `setEditorAreaActive` and `setPartState` methods being called while `partOpened` is being processed. You could try using `Display.asyncExec` to delay calling these until after the `partOpened` code has completed.

Something like:

```java
public void partOpened(final IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
  Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        if (partRef instanceof IEditorReference) {
          //force editor area visible
          partRef.getPage().setEditorAreaVisible(true);
          // if the editors are currently minimimized and we try to maximize them, then we'll cause a bug.
          if (partRef.getPage().getPartState(partRef) == IWorkbenchPage.STATE_MINIMIZED) {
              return; // so exit here
          }
          //check preferences
          final boolean maximized = EnterpriseManager.isMaximized();
          if (maximized) {
            partRef.getPage().setPartState(partRef, IWorkbenchPage.STATE_MAXIMIZED);
          }
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. the editor still opens in a smaller window

Comment: What is stranger, though, is it opens the first time in a smaller window, but on subsequent editor selections in the same session, it opens maximized, as is desired.